# Splitting text using delimiter and build html page

Tags: python, html, yattag

I have a text file like this:-

```
-----Starting Step for step1-----
text1
text2
text3
-----Ending Step for step1-----
-----Starting Step for step2-----
text4
text5
text6
-----Starting Step for step3-----
text7
text8
text9
-----Ending Step for step3-----

text10
text11
text12
-----Ending Step for step2-----
```

After opening the log file, I have been trying to search for patterns Starting Step and respective contents.

I'm saving it in the variable value, Now once if i get another Starting Step pattern before I get a pattern Ending step i consider that as the child for the earlier parent.

```
with open('C:\Python27\sample.log','r') as f:
    with tag('html'):
        with tag('body'):
            with tag('pre'):
                for line in f:
                        value=re.findall(r'Starting Step for (\w+)',line)
                        new_value=re.findall(r'Ending Step for (\w+)',line)
                        if value not in parent_tag_stop and value not in parent_tag_start:
                            if parent_tag_start:
                                parent_tag_start.append(value)
                            else:
                               child_tag[parent_tag_start[-1]] =value

                        elif new_value:
                                parent_tag_stop.append(value)
                                if tag==new_value[0]:
                                    with tag('a', href='#{0}'.format(new_value)):
                                        text(value)
                                    value=''
                        else:
                            value+=line
```

I want to split each block from starting step to ending step and create an html page with step1, step2 etc as anchor tags and the respective content as its text,step3 here will be child anchor under step 2 and its contents will be part of step2 also

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right output structure, but I came with this solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from pprint import pprint

data = '''-----Starting Step for step1-----
text1
text2
text3
-----Ending Step for step1-----
-----Starting Step for step2-----
text4
text5
text6
-----Starting Step for step3-----
text7
text8
text9
-----Ending Step for step3-----

text10
text11
text12
-----Ending Step for step2-----'''


data = re.sub(r'-----Starting Step for step(\d+)-----', r'<a href="#step\1" /><div>', data)
data = re.sub(r'-----Ending Step for step\d+-----', r'</div>', data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="#step1">
  </a>
  <div>
   text1
text2
text3
  </div>
  <a href="#step2">
  </a>
  <div>
   text4
text5
text6
   <a href="#step3">
   </a>
   <div>
    text7
text8
text9
   </div>
   text10
text11
text12
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```